# Is there any AWS Support for Binderhub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, aws-cloudformation, kubectl, binderhub

I want to connect CodeCommit Repository and ECR with Binderhub. Is it possible? There is no documentation about it so currently I am using Dockerhub and Github but I would like to switch to AWS since there is also my k8s cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sort of stated backwards given how these things go. The community drives the guides using various tech. While sometimes the tech providers offer resources and even help, you'd want to look to the Binderhub community for quides to how to use AWS. As an example, when I was using [The Littlest JupyterHub](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/) on AWS, there was no guide. I looked at the other guides and adapted it using what I knew about using AWS. (And then when I had it worked out, I posted what I worked out as the basis for what now exists [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/amazon.html).)

Looking at [Zero to BinderHub](https://binderhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zero-to-binderhub/index.html) has some guides for some of the providers, however, not Amazon. It looks like someone has posted working this out some and maybe that below will guide you, in addition to what is posted at [Zero to BinderHub](https://binderhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zero-to-binderhub/index.html) and the [Zero to JupyterHub Guide](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

- [Setting up a BinderHub with AWS](https://github.com/TomasBeuzen/binderhub-aws-docs)

There's also [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/aws-integration-work/864/4?u=fomightez) that said it was at the 'proof-of-concept' state at the time.

If you work out something that will be useful, please at least post it here, and preferably integrate it into the documentation.